# System of n vectors forms a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I Could use some polya-style prodding, I have tried so many different things I think the wheels are coming off :/ Is any of this on the right track?

> The following is known about a system of vectors $e_1,...e_n$ in a
> linear space $K$
>
> 1. Every vector $x$ has expansion of the form
>    $x =\xi_1e_1 + ... + \xi_ne_n$
> 2. the expansion is unique for some fixed $x_0\in K$
>
> Show the system forms a basis in $K$.

**EDIT 3: Proving that the expansion of the zero vector is unique.**

Suppose there are two expansions of the zero element
$$ 0 = 0_1 = \alpha_1e_1 +...+\alpha_ne_n$$ and $$0 = 0_2 = \lambda_1e_1 +...+\lambda_ne_n$$
It is given that there exists $x_0 \in K$ such that it has a unique expansion, let $x_0 = \xi_1e_1 +...+\xi_ne_n$.

$K$ is a linear space, so there exists a neutral element, therefore

$$ x_0 + 0 = x_0$$
We have assumed two distinct expansions of zero, $0_1$ and $0_1$ so that
$$ x_0 + 0_1 = x_0$$
$$ x_0 + 0_2 = x_0$$
substituting their respective expansions we obtain equations
$$\xi_1e_1 +...+\xi_ne_n + \alpha_1e_1 +...+\alpha_ne_n = x_0$$
$$ (\xi_1 + \alpha_1)e_1 +...+ (\xi_n + \alpha_n)e_n = x_0$$
and
$$\xi_1e_1 +...+\xi_ne_n + \lambda_1e_1 +...+\lambda_ne_n = x_0$$
$$ (\xi_1 + \lambda_1)e_1 +...+ (\xi_n + \lambda_n)e_n = x_0$$

By assumption, the coefficients of the expansions of $0_1$ and $0_2$ are different, i.e that $\lambda_i \neq \alpha_i$ for some $1 \leq i \leq n$

Therefore, there exists some $(\xi_i + \alpha_i) \neq (\xi_i + \lambda_i) $ contradicting the uniqueness of $x_0$ and proving there cannot be two different expansions of the zero vector.

Comment: Why is the expansion of $e_1$ unique?

Comment: because exists  a unique expansion of $e_1$, whatever it may be, when added to the zero vector must still give the unique expansion in terms of all $e_1... e_n$ ?

Comment: You are not given that there is a unique expansion of $e_1$, though. You are given (1) that there *is* an expansion of $e_1$, just like there is an expansion of any other vector, and (2) that for some $x_0 \in K$ (but probably not $e_1$) the expansion is unique. For that matter, you're not given that there is a unique expansion of $0$.

Comment: oh okay thanks! and so 'some' just means there exists at least one?

Comment: If I prove the 0 vector in a linear space is unique, can I say that it's expansion is unique or does that have to be proven too?

Comment: Those are completely separate. "The $0$ vector is unique" is about whether there is only one element of $K$ that acts as an additive identity. "The expansion of $0$ is unique" is about ways of writing $0$ as $\xi_1 e_1 + \dots + \xi_n e_n$: it depends on $e_1, \dots, e_n$, not just on $K$.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your help. I posted my attempt to show the expansion of zero is unique, but I feel like what I've done actually might still 'depend' on the linear independence of $e_1...e_n$ which is still to be established.

Comment: You're right that what you have doesn't work yet. You still have an assumption about $x_0$ you haven't used! It's there for a reason.

Comment: Ah I again wasn't clear on that exact meaning. I've attempted to use it. The very last statement I am a little unsure about though. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Don't think of what you're doing as "finding an expansion for $0$". Of course you know from the start that $0e_1 + \dots + 0e_n$ is an expansion for $0$. Showing that the expansion is unique means showing that there **cannot be two different expansions for $0$**. Since you are proving a negative, this is easiest to do by contradiction: suppose there are two different expansions for $0$, and show that there are two different expansions for $x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take a vector $x_1$ and two expansions for it,
$$\begin{align} x_1 &= \sum a_j e_j \\
x_1 &= \sum b_j e_j. \end{align}$$
Also fix an expansion for $\widetilde{x} = x_0 - x_1,$
$$ \widetilde{x} = \sum c_j e_j. $$
Then you compute that
$$ \begin{align} x_0 = x_1 + \widetilde{x} &=
\sum (a_j + c_j) e_j \\
&= \sum(b_j + c_j) e_j. \end{align}$$
Deduce that $a_j = b_j$, and thus any two expansions for an arbitrary vector $x_1$ are actually the same.